# After I build ICU using VS2010, how do I merge the .dat file into the .dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, icu

Merging would be ideal. A standalone .dat file would be ok, but will it automatically get picked up?

If it gets picked up, what should I set ICU_DATA_DIR to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitute .dat should be placed in icu\source\data\in

Answer (score 1):

- You can't merge into a DLL.
- You can rebuild a DLL, by replacing the data file you noted in `icu\source\data\in\`
- If you set environment variable `ICU_DATA` or preprocessor `ICU_DATA_DIR` or `u_setDataDirectory()` then give the full path to the `icudt*.dat` file. [more info](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata)

Comment: What is the mechanism by which the DLL is rebuilt?

Comment: @tofutim you can just rebuild the project, or the makedata project

Comment: Can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218640/compiling-icu-using-arm-linux-androideabi-4-4-3, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168962/icu-library-in-android-ndk/9224077#9224077