# Compiling ICU for Android: __timezone' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, android-ndk, icu

In attempting to compile ICU49 using Android NDKv7b, I ran into the following:

```
/home/tim/icu49/icu/source/common/putil.cpp: In function 'int32_t uprv_timezone_49()':
/home/tim/icu49/icu/source/common/putil.cpp:637: error: '__timezone' was not declared in this scope
/home/tim/icu49/icu/source/common/putil.cpp: At global scope:
/home/tim/icu49/icu/source/common/putil.cpp:2253: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
```

using

```
export ANDROIDVER=8
export AR=/usr/bin/ar
export BASE=/home/tim/icu49
export HOST_ICU=$BASE/icu
export ICU_CROSS_BUILD=$BASE/icu-linux
export NDK_ROOT=$BASE/android-ndk-r7b
export CPPFLAGS="-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-$ANDROIDVER/arch-arm/usr/include/ -O3 -fno-short-wchar -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_GNUC_UTF16_STRING=0 -fno-short-enums -DU_HAVE_NL_LANGINFO_CODESET=0 -D__STDC_INT64__"
export LDFLAGS="-lc -Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-$ANDROIDVER/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-$ANDROIDVER/arch-arm/usr/lib/"

export OLDPATH=$PATH
export PATH=/home/tim/icu49/api$ANDROIDVER/bin:$PATH

$NDK_ROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-$ANDROIDVER --install-dir=$BASE/api$ANDROIDVER

$HOST_ICU/source/configure --with-cross-build=$ICU_CROSS_BUILD --enable-extras=no --enable-strict=no -enable-static --enable-shared=no --enable-tests=no --enable-samples=no --enable-dyload=no --enable-tools=no --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a patch](http://pastebin.com/U6cCQq83) for that particular issue (made with ICU 4.8 but should give you the idea).

Also, [see the discussion here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944207/unicode-support-in-android-ndk)

Comment: Thanks NuSkooler. What does the patch do?

Comment: The particular patch allows for uprv_timezone() to compile/work correctly on Android/NDK. The rest of the patches in the other discussion are for ICU on Android as a whole. Again these are from older versions of ICU but many of it still applies in 4.9 I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using -DU_TIMEZONE=0 in CPPFLAGS. But not clear if this is the right approach.